# VMware: Ubuntu 18 Kernel panic

Tags: kernel, 18.04, bug-reporting

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18 on a new laptop (Asus, windows 10) with VMware.

I get the following error while installing:

[image: screenshot]

Any way to fix this ?

Comment: Been facing the same problem the last couple of days. It seems to me that the newer linux kernel (v4.15) has changed the way the kernel stack protector works. Running Ubuntu 16.04 (v4.10) seems to work with no issues, but running anything with a newer kernel version (Kali 2018.2, Ubuntu 18.04), throws this error. It also seems as though this issue is solely related to Intel's mobile CPUs. I did come across this, https://github.com/gentoo/vmware/issues/34 He mentions that recompiling the kernel works, but I haven't tried that out yet!